# Tune parameters not detected with tidymodels

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidymodels

Untill last update the following code works:

```
model_recipe_prep <- recipe( leads_dda ~ ., data = train_data) %>%
  step_rm(dt,cost) %>% 
  step_normalize( all_numeric(), -all_outcomes() ) %>% 
  step_BoxCox( all_numeric(), -all_outcomes(), -starts_with("number_")) %>%
  step_dummy( all_nominal(), one_hot = TRUE) %>% 
  step_poly(impressions, degree = tune() ) %>% 
  step_nzv(all_predictors() ) 

# ---- Metrics ----
model_control_metrics <- metric_set( rmse, mae, rsq )
model_control         <- control_grid(save_pred = TRUE)

model_baseline <- linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm") %>% 
  set_mode("regression")

set.seed(3456)
model_baseline_recipe_grid  <- expand.grid(degree = 1:3)
#model_baseline_engine_grid <- grid_regular()
#model_baseline_grid        <- merge(model_recipe_base_linear, model_baseline_engine_grid)

model_baseline_tune <- tune_grid(
  model_baseline,
  model_recipe_prep,
  resamples = train_data_kfolds,
  grid = model_baseline_recipe_grid,
  control = model_control,
  metrics = model_control_metrics
)
```

But now I start receiving an error like:

> Warning messages: 1: No tuning parameters have been detected,
> performance will be evaluated using the resamples with no tuning. Did
> you want [fit_resamples()]?  2: All models failed in tune_grid(). See
> the `.notes` column.

and in the .notes field I've got something like:

> "recipe: Error: You cannot `prep()` a tuneable recipe. Argument(s)
> with `tune()`: 'degree'. Do you want to use a tuning function such as
> `tune_grid()`?

Maybe I'm missing something really stupid, but I can't figure out how make it works again.

In addition if I check with

```
tune_args(model_recipe_prep)
```

I've got an empty nibble as the model_recipe_prep has no tenable params.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, we have learned there may be a mismatch between the new version of recipes that just went to CRAN and the current tune version on CRAN in certain situations. We are working on a tune release ASAP but in the meantime, if you are able to install from GitHub via `devtools::install_github("tidymodels/tune")` that should solve your problems, and you should see something like this:

```r
library(tidymodels)

rec1 <- recipe( mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) %>%
    step_normalize( all_numeric(), -all_outcomes() ) %>% 
    step_BoxCox( all_numeric(), -all_outcomes(), -starts_with("number_")) %>%
    step_dummy( all_nominal(), one_hot = TRUE) %>% 
    step_poly(disp, degree = tune() ) %>% 
    step_nzv(all_predictors() ) 

tunable(rec1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   name       call_info        source component component_id
#>   <chr>      <list>           <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       
#> 1 degree     <named list [2]> recipe step_poly poly_Dj0QK  
#> 2 freq_cut   <named list [2]> recipe step_nzv  nzv_zIzsm   
#> 3 unique_cut <named list [2]> recipe step_nzv  nzv_zIzsm
tune_args(rec1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 6
#>   name   tunable id     source component component_id
#>   <chr>  <lgl>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>       
#> 1 degree TRUE    degree recipe step_poly poly_Dj0QK
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>